# How do I lint .html files of my Angular Project using ESLint in my VSCode

Tags: angular, eslint, lint, eslintrc, angular-eslint

ESLint is already installed in my Angular project and linting all the typescript files. I have also written some set of rules for typescript files to display warnings instead of errors. But the rules I wrote for html didn't work. I am not able to lint my html files

**eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": ["projects/**/*"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": ["tsconfig.json", "e2e/tsconfig.json"],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/dot-notation": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": [
          "off",
          {
            "accessibility": "explicit"
          }
        ],
        "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "error",
        "brace-style": ["warn", "1tbs"],
        "id-blacklist": "off",
        "id-match": "off",
        "max-len": "off",
        "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
        "valid-typeof": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/member-ordering": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/quotes": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/semi": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions": "warn",
        "arrow-body-style": "warn",
        "arrow-spacing": "warn",
        "curly": "warn",
        "eqeqeq": "warn",
        "indent": ["warn", 2],
        "max-line-length": "off",
        "member-access": "off",
        "no-bitwise": "warn",
        "no-console": [
          "warn",
          { "allow": ["info", "warn", "error", "time", "timeEnd", "trace"] }
        ],
        "no-debugger": "warn",
        "no-empty": "off",
        "no-eval": "warn",
        "no-shadow": "warn",
        "no-string-literal": "off",
        "no-trailing-spaces": "warn",
        "no-var": "warn",
        "object-literal-sort-keys": "off",
        "prefer-const": "warn",
        "quote-props": "warn",
        "radix": "warn",
        "space-before-blocks": "warn",
        "space-infix-ops": "warn",
        "space-in-parens": "warn",
        "no-multi-spaces": "warn",
        "comma-dangle": "warn",
        "default-case": "warn",
        "eol-last": "warn",
        "guard-for-in": "warn",
        "key-spacing": "warn",
        "keyword-spacing": "warn",
        "no-extra-parens": "warn",
        "no-extra-semi": "warn",
        "no-multiple-empty-lines": "warn",
        "no-unused-expressions": "warn",
        "variable-name": "off"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"],
      "rules": {
        "eqeqeq": "warn",
        "indent": ["warn", 2],
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "cat",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build-high": "node --max_old_space_size=7000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --output-hashing=all",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "serve": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 & ng serve --open",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-prod": "node ./replace.build.js && ng build --prod --aot=false",
    "bundle-analyze": "node --max_old_space_size=7000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --stats-json && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats-es2015.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@amcharts/amcharts3-angular": "^2.2.4",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.10.21",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.104",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^25.2.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^25.2.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.0.3",
    "angular2-counto": "^1.2.5",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.4",
    "angular2-tinymce": "^2.1.2",
    "auth0-js": "^9.15.0",
    "auth0-lock": "^11.29.0",
    "d3": "^4.12.2",
    "d3-scale-chromatic": "^1.3.3",
    "dom-autoscroller": "^2.3.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.4.1",
    "radial-progress-chart": "0.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "signalr-no-jquery": "^0.2.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "underscore.deepclone": "^0.1.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.9.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.20",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "1.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.7.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.9",
    "@types/node": "^15.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.7.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.6.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "replace-in-file": "^6.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "cat": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/Web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
              "node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "src/ngsw-config.json",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "cat:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "cat:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "cat:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
              "node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/Web.config"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "cat-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "cat:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "cat",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried writing rules for html files. You can find 2 rules, "eqeqeq" and "indent" at the bottom of my eslintre.json file.
And my expectations were that it would start linting html files just like I it is linting all typescript files of my project.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply rules which are designed to run on JavaScript code on your Angular templates. This does not work, the rules understand JavaScript syntax but don't understand Angular's template syntax.

For the `eqeqeq` rule, luckily the Angular ESLint template plugin contains an equivalent rule `@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq`. You can set up the rule like the following:

```json
{
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": "warn"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For the `indent` rule there is no equivalent rule in Angular ESLint. They will never add such rule, because it's formatting related and [they decided to stop implementation of formatting related rules](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/main/docs/FORMATTING_RULES.md). You would need to implement a custom ESLint rule. For easier implementation you can use Angular ESLint's template parser.